# Heap Corruption Error with stitching (Opencv & C++)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm tried a simple code and  had this error message:

```
Debug Assertion Failed!
Program:...
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt\crtwin32\misc\dbgheap.c
Line:1424
Expression: _pFirstBlock==pHead
```

Code I used:

```
int main()
{
    vector<Mat>img1;
    img1.push_back(imread("test_fisheye1.jpg"));
    img1.push_back(imread("test_fisheye2.jpg"));
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();
    Mat lol;
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(img1, lol);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm Using Visual Studio 2013 Community with VC12 compiler. I'm in debug mode and I using debug lib, and builded Opencv 3.1.0 for visual studio 2013 V12 Win64 using CMake.
Thanks to my debugging researches, I found that the Error comes from stitcher.stitch()

 I already saw the same post on stackoverflow but it didn't help me ...

Comment: Be sure that your project is x64, and that you're using debug libs in debug mode, and release libs in release mode

Comment: This what i wrote :/