# Downgrade Visual studio 2015 update 3 to update 1

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Does anyone knows how to do that ?
I would like to do that because I need to use CUDA's functions in OPENCV and CUDA is only supported on MSVC 2015 Update 1 ...

Comment: Have you tried using system restore (i think each time you do a VS update Windows creates a restore point) ?

Comment: Do you mean that tere is a restore function on VS?

Comment: No - it's part of Windows - type in System Restore in Start->Run

Comment: Ok, That's what I was thinking about, but unfortunately , the computer that I am using belongs to the society i'm working for and I'm not the only one using it :/ Thank you

Comment: Seems rather implausible that an updater would *intentionally* remove an previously installed component.  Extraordinary claims require extraordinary evidence, you did not provide any.  Not even an error message.

Comment: I'm Sorry Mister Passant, but CUDA toolkit does not support Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 +, like  written on the internet like here : https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/883704/cuda-setup-and-installation/when-will-visual-studio-2015-be-supported-/5
And since i Still wanted to try to install Cuda, the installer told me that no  supported software  was detected on my computer. So the question is, did I really had to make a screenshot to show that it's not detected? I think not.

Comment: Now if you're talking about an error, here is my post of yesterday which no nobody answered (I Mean it did not helped me resolve my problem ) :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103532/heap-corruption-error-with-stitching-opencv-c

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, CUDA with OpenCV is supported in VS 2013. You can install VS 2013 Community Edition in parallel and in VS 2015 you can set in the settings Platform Toolset to Visual Studio 2013 (v120)

Comment: Yes I already tried this soltion, but I have issues running my program ( Stitching functions crashes giving me _Block_Type_Is_Valid (pHead->nBlockUse) error and I didn't find any solution about that.... And it works perfectly when compiling on Visual Studio 2015 ...

Comment: OpenCV also needs to be compiled with VS 2013. Are you linking to the prebuild libs in the v12 folder and in the PATH variable is also vc12/bin?

Comment: I Linked my libs with direct link, didn't want to make an environment variable so i'm sure that they are linked right :s

Comment: But these are two separate things. PATH is only for the the exe to find the correct dll, this has nothing to do with linking. In Visual Studio you need to set under Linker -> General -> "Additional Library Directories" the directory to the lib file which will get linked. That you need to change when changing from v140 to v120.

Comment: ok, but does the exe watch in the current folder first? because my dlls are all in the current folder

Comment: yes, you can also copy the dll from opencv\build\x64\vc12\bin in the same folder where the exe file is located. That should work.